# HTML normal button to submit form

Tags: javascript, php, html

Please help me, I dont know why never enters in the condition "if (isset($_POST['buscar']))"

When you press the "button" I want to send a submit

if an error happens cancel the submit

otherwise send the submit

when in php, ask for the variable 'buscar' and is where the error happens

and do not understand why not enter the condition

```
<?php
# Load...
$data_buscar = array();

# Buscar...
if (isset($_POST['buscar']))
{
    if (!empty($_POST['id_ingrediente']))
    {
        $id_ingrediente = $_POST['id_ingrediente'];
        $query = "SELECT *
        FROM INGREDIENTE
        WHERE ID_INGREDIENTE = '$id_ingrediente';";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $data_buscar[] = $row;
        }
        mysql_free_result($result);
    }
}

?>
```

here display

```
<?php
    print_r($data_buscar);
?>
```

here is the function in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function()
    {
        document.form1.buscar.addEventListener("click", buscar_click);
    }

    function buscar_click(e)
    {
        if (//something)
        {
            alert("err");
        }
        else
        {
            document.form1.submit();
        }
    }

<body>
    <form name="form1" action="organizador.php" method="post" target="_self">
        <label>Id del Ingrediente:</label>
        <input class="textbox" type="text" name="id_ingrediente">
        <input class="but" type="button" name="buscar" value="Buscar">
    </form>
</body>
```

:)

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You have 100 button in One form, Only one form button value will submit, where you click on.. (My Experience)

If you not click on button then button value Will not submit

Use Hidden input Field It Will WORK :)

```
<body>
    <form name="form1" action="organizador.php" method="post" target="_self">
        <label>Id del Ingrediente:</label>
        <input class="textbox" type="text" name="id_ingrediente">

        <input class="but" type="hidden" name="buscar" value="Buscar">

        <input class="but" type="button" value="Buscar">
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If a form is submitted via AJAX the button value is not sent.

You can perform client side validation by checking for the error, and if one is present returning false which will cancel the default action of the button (to submit the form).

If there is no error, allow the button click to perform it's default action of submitting the form.

```
if (//error)
{
  alert("err");
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `buscar` in your `$_POST`. You only have `id_ingrediente`. Tht's why `isset($_POST['buscar'])` is false.

You have to write:

```
if ( isset($_POST['id_ingrediente'])) ...
```

Or something similar.

Comment: the problem is 
I have more buttons for the same form 
as I can differentiate each, if I use the condition 
if (isset ($ _ POST ['id_ingrediente'])) ...